# Issue with floating divs not moving to the

Tags: html, css, layout

I am attempting to make sort of blog. A fluid layout that mainly stacks each individual "box" on top of each other. I have created a CSS class that floats each "box" to the left side. I have toyed with this for literally days and was forced to--after viewing other user's question on this site for months--to post my first ever question to stackoverflow.com in hopes with someone with a fresh mind can fix my issue.

I know that my current CSS usage (the floating) is not the answer for what I am trying to do. It however is the easiest way that I can convey to you a graphical idea of what I am trying to do. Here is a link to an image to better show you what I am talking about: http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/2067/97o9.png

As you can see because my use of `float: left` boxs that are longer than others are stopping smaller boxes from getting all the way to the left side. My question to you is: How would I be able to create this 3 column fluid layout and allow for both tall and short boxs to be used together and in different columns. I greatly appreciate any help that I can get. And I apologize for the lack of detail on the issue.

For reference, below the div class that contains each individual box:
**CSS**

```
.blogPositioner {
        width: 300px;
        height: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 16px;
        padding-right: 16px;
}
```

Comment: hi...welcome to SO....please provide HTML markup too!!

Answer (score 1):

Try [**jQuery Masonry**](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/) It works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space

Comment: I've used this before, it's well worth a look at for this type of thing.

Comment: I attempted to use this library but it is not working for me. If it works it will do exactly what I am wanting. I will continue to refer to the documentation and try to get it working. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

instead of float, why not try display:inline-block?

Comment: @kinsesyete I am aware of the abilities of the display property. The issue is that it does not account for the different height of other divs and just create a new row with a uniform vertical starting point all the way across. Creating an empty space between one row and an other. I am wanting a fluid layout that accounts for different heights. I appreciate your comment, just wanted to clarify my goals with this design.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
display: inline-block;
```

first, to see if that helps at all...

but also, if you're looking for 3 columns, you should change or make sure you html has 3 columns (div columns) in it.

Lets say you have 3 main divs which make up the columns. Their CSS could be like this

```
   div-left {
              float: left;
              display: inline-block;
              width: 33%;
            }
     div-center {
              float: left;
              display: inline-block;
              width: 34%;
            }
        div-right {
             float: left;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 33%;
         }
```

The above code would be if you want each column to be roughly the same size. Or if you wanted the center div to be 60% of the page, just put width: 60% for center, and then 20% for the left and right divs.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your divs have variable height, simply use `<div style="clear:both; width:100%"></div>` after each third div.